# How to make my second (right) Y-axis start at 0 in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How to make my second (right) Y-axis start at 0 in Google sheets? I can do it with Excel very easy, but don't know how to do it after I spend a lot of time.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*It's not possible*

### Workaround

You can use the column `A` as a column for index marks. For example, you can put in `A1` `=sequence(rows(A:A),1,0,1)` and you will get a column with indexes starting at zero. You can also narrow the width.

Comment: Damn! No solutions so far?